# Error Stating "Bad version in .class file"

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I worked with a JSP code and executed the same under the tomcat5.5 server. It worked fined. Now I have copied the same code to the other system under tomcat server. But while submission of that jsp file, am receiving the following error. What might be the cause for the error? Please advise.

```
root cause:
javax.servlet.ServletException: Bad version number in .class file (unable to load class myfirst.SearchLink)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:774)
org.apache.jsp.Test_jsp._jspService(Test_jsp.java:70)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file (unable to load class myfirst.SearchLink)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1962)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:931)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1403)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1282)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:125)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
org.apache.jsp.Test_jsp._jspService(Test_jsp.java:51)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

**UPDATE**

Even after compiling all the java code I have, in the current version of java, I get the same error..

**RECENT UPDATE**

@Pangea Yes am using myfirst.SearchLink in my JSP code as follows,

`myfirst.SearchLink o=new myfirst.SearchLink();
        String result=o.checkURL(url);`

And my java code for SearchLink is as below,

```
package myfirst;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.sql.*;
public class SearchLink{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


}

public String checkURL(String link)throws SQLException{
    Connection con=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    Statement stmtR=null;
    String mem;
    if(con==null){
            SQLConnection.setURL("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.2.53\\SQL2005;user=sa;password=365media;DatabaseName=LN_ADWEEK");
            con=SQLConnection.getNewConnection();
            stmt=con.createStatement();
            stmtR=con.createStatement();
    }
    try{
        ResultSet rs;
        boolean hasRows=false;
        rs=stmt.executeQuery("select url from urls_linkins where url='"+link+"'");
        while(rs.next()){
            hasRows=true;
            //String mem=rs.getString(1);
            rs.close();
            return "This URL already exists in DB";
        }
        rs.close();
        if (!hasRows)
        {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            String domain=url.getHost();
            String Str="This URL does not exist in DB<br><br><br>";
            rs=stmtR.executeQuery("select url from urls_linkins where url like '%"+domain+"%'");
            boolean flag=false;
            while(rs.next()){
                if(!flag){
                Str=Str+"<Br>"+"Similar Domains in DB are";
                }
                flag=true;
                mem=rs.getString(1);
                //System.out.println("Similar Domains already in DB"+mem);
                Str=Str+"<Br>"+mem;
            }
            return Str;
        }
        return "This URL does not exist in DB";
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    }finally{
        if(stmtR!=null){
            stmtR.close();
        }
        if(stmt!=null){
            stmt.close();
        }
        if(con!= null){
            con.close();
        }

    }
}


public String addURL(String link,String source)throws SQLException{
        Connection con=null;
        Statement stmt=null;
        Statement stmtR=null;
        final String rssvar="Rss";
        if(con==null){
                SQLConnection.setURL("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.2.53\\SQL2005;user=sa;password=365media;DatabaseName=LN_ADWEEK");
                con=SQLConnection.getNewConnection();
                stmt=con.createStatement();
                stmtR=con.createStatement();
    }
        try{
            PreparedStatement insertUrlStatement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO urls_linkins(url, source_name, is_active, is_periodic, Link_Type, New_Entry) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            //insertUrlStatement.setInt(1, 21211);
            insertUrlStatement.setString(1, link);
            insertUrlStatement.setString(2, source);
            insertUrlStatement.setInt(3, 1);
            insertUrlStatement.setInt(4, 0);
            insertUrlStatement.setString(5, rssvar);
            insertUrlStatement.setInt(6, 1);
            insertUrlStatement.executeUpdate();
            insertUrlStatement.close();
            return "The URL has been added to the Database";}
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getMessage();
        }finally{
            if(stmtR!=null){
                stmtR.close();
            }
            if(stmt!=null){
                stmt.close();
            }
            if(con!= null){
                con.close();
            }
        }


}

public String addURL1(String link,String source)throws SQLException{
        Connection con=null;
        Statement stmt=null;
        Statement stmtR=null;
        final String other="Other";
        if(con==null){
                SQLConnection.setURL("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.2.53\\SQL2005;user=sa;password=365media;DatabaseName=LN_ADWEEK");
                con=SQLConnection.getNewConnection();
                stmt=con.createStatement();
                stmtR=con.createStatement();
    }
        try{
            PreparedStatement insertUrlStatement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO urls_linkins(url, source_name, is_active, is_periodic, Link_Type, New_Entry) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            //insertUrlStatement.setInt(1, 21211);
            insertUrlStatement.setString(1, link);
            insertUrlStatement.setString(2, source);
            insertUrlStatement.setInt(3, 1);
            insertUrlStatement.setInt(4, 0);
            insertUrlStatement.setString(5, other);
            insertUrlStatement.setInt(6, 1);
            insertUrlStatement.executeUpdate();
            insertUrlStatement.close();
            return "The URL has been added to the Database";}
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getMessage();
        }finally{
            if(stmtR!=null){
                stmtR.close();
            }
            if(stmt!=null){
                stmt.close();
            }
            if(con!= null){
                con.close();
            }
        }
}

public String addmultiple(String file)throws SQLException{
        return file;
}
}
```

Comment: Run one of your class files against the code here http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0544.html. This will tell you what your code is compiled against. Also see which JRE is being used by the tomcat.

Comment: 50 . 0 is the result out of the given code...

Comment: what about the JRE being used by your old tomcat?

Comment: am sorry.. am unaware of that.. how to find the same?

Comment: The tomcat server also uses JRE 1.6

Comment: is this the JRE of the 'other system' you are talking about in yoour post "Now I have copied the same code to the other system under tomcat server"

Comment: Are you using myfirst.SearchLink in your jsp? If so can you post the JSP and your class.

Comment: I have updated the question with required codes

Comment: I wanted to check if you are using any features in the code (like generics) that meed special indication to the web-container that you need to use specific Java version. But it seems like you are not. So we should focus on the class and JDK incompatibilities only. How do you know that new tomcat and the current tomcat and new system on other tomcat are running against the same JRE? I need to know what specific tests you have run. I would also suggest you to compile your class using the "javac -target 1.4" and try it on both the servers.

Comment: @Pangea I just noticed that there is Java 1.5 also there in my system. So, let me know how to check which version of JRE tomcat server is using?

Comment: add the below code to a new jsp and see what gets printed on the current tomcat and new system on the other tomcat " out.println("Java Version = "+ System.getProperty("java.version"));

Comment: @Pangea.. Surprising.. `Java Version = 1.5.0_04` This is the reply... How can I change this?

Comment: No you need to run the same thing at 2 places...where the code is working and the other place where it is raising the exception

Comment: I am running the code currently at one place only. My previous system is formatted and its no more :(

Comment: @Pangea I resolved the issue. Thanks for the extended support

Comment: What was the actual issue though?

Comment: The actual issue was as firstly predicted by you.. Java version supported by tomcat server was 1.5. But I have compiled java programs using java 1.6.

Comment: @LGAP: How did you resolve the issue? I mean how did you change the Java version of tomcat?. I've changed the JAVA_HOME, but no help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means your code is compiled against the java version that is not supported by the tomcat server you are running it in. May be you moved your code to older version of tomcat than 5.5 that is using older version of java

Comment: Compiling the java code with the version of the current system am using will do the job?

Comment: If they're running the same major version of the JDK/JRE, then yes

Comment: Even after compiling all the java codes in the current version of java and restarting the tomcat server, I find the same error. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're running a newer version of the code on an old JVM version (e.g running Java 5 code on JDK 4). I'm assuming the other Tomcat is running an older version of java compared to java running on Tomcat 5.5 server.

Answer (score 0):

I had same exception but i changed setting as follows that worked me:

- Right click on your eclipse project select properties
- Pop up will display all setting tree select Java Compiler
- Then select compiler compliance level drop down as you want and again Build project
- restart tomcat (i had used tomcat 6)