# How to change Java version used by TOMCAT?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat5.5, java-home

I have Java 1.6 and Tomcat 5.5 installed on my system.

But Tomcat 5.5 accesses Java 1.5 and hence as the outcome I get the error `Bad version number in .class file` while executing java code with JSP.

How can I change the Tomcat version to Java 1.6?

**UPDATE**

I tried changing the JVM that the tomcat5w.exe is pointing to the version 1.6 and now I am out of the `Bad version in .class file` error. But now, I get the following error.

```
exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:498)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
myfirst.SearchLink.checkURL(SearchLink.java:20)
org.apache.jsp.Test_jsp._jspService(Test_jsp.java:52)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

What might be the root cause?

Comment: your exception now is completely different. It's for a new question. (but do some search before that ;) )

Comment: I rectified the issue... Thanks a lot for your support Bozho.. Sincere Thanks

Comment: Check Tomcat Tutorial: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html  ,    e.g. tomcat7  //US/Tomcat7  --JavaHome  D:\Java8

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When you open catalina.sh / catalina.bat, you can see :

> Environment Variable Prequisites
>
> JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.

So, set your environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to point to Java 6. Also make sure `JRE_HOME` is pointing to the same target, if it is set.

Update: since you are on Windows, [see here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519) for how to manage your environment variables

Comment: I could not find both these file catalina.sh / catalina.bat in my Tomact 5.5 folder

Comment: they are in `/bin`. But this is not the point. You have to set the _environment_ variables. Don't touch the catalina files.

Comment: You mean changing JVM `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_04\bin\client\jvm.dll` from this?

Comment: JAVA_HOME is directing to version 1.6 only.. But when i used the code `out.println("Java Version = "+ System.getProperty("java.version"));` in my jsp code I got the version as 1.5.0_04 \

Comment: JRE HOME is not set.. I cannot find it in the section where I find the JAVA_HOME

Comment: How are you running tomcat? From command line? Service? Try from command-line, and check the value of JAVA_HOME (using echo %JAVA_HOME%).

Comment: I am running tomcat on command line only... `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10` This results on using the echo in command line.

Comment: My actual requirement is described `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070443/error-stating-bad-version-in-class-file`here more clearly...

Comment: and what is the output of running startup.bat ? There should be 4 lines showing different _HOME variables.

Comment: While running the tomcat5.exe file, the first few lines contains many locations out of which two locations are poiting to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10` only

Comment: But I dont know how i got the version as 1.5.0_04 when i used `out.println("Java Version = "+ System.getProperty("java.version"));`

Comment: Try starting it with `startup.bat`. If it still does not work, look into setenv.bat, startup.bat and catalina.bat for 1.5

Comment: @Bozho Done with the version problem.. Kindly resolve my updated question.

Answer (score 23):

**You can change the JDK or JRE location using the following steps:**

1. open the **terminal** or **cmd**.
2. go to the `[tomcat-home]\bin` directory.

       ex: `c:\tomcat8\bin`
3. write the following
   command: `Tomcat8W //ES//Tomcat8`
4. will open dialog, select the **java tab(top pane)**.
5. change the Java virtual Machine value.
6. click **OK**.

***note:***
in Apache TomEE same steps, but **step (3)** the command must be: `TomEE //ES`

Comment: For some reason I had the default Java path checked off

Answer (score 21):

If you use the standard scripts to launch Tomcat (i.e. you haven't installed Tomcat as a windows service), you can use the setenv.bat file, to set your JRE_HOME version.

> On Windows, create the file `%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat`, with content:
>
> `set "JRE_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre1.6.0_20"`
>
> `exit /b 0`

And that should be it.

You can test this using %CATALINA_BASE%\bin\configtest.bat (Disclaimer: I've only checked this with a Tomcat7 installation).

**Further Reading:**

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/RUNNING.txt - Section:
  'Advanced Configuration - Multiple Tomcat Instances'
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt - Section: '(3.4)
  Using the "setenv" script (optional, recommended)'

Answer (score 13):

In Eclipse it is very easy to point Tomcat to a new JVM (in this example JRE6). My problem was I couldn't find where to do it. Here is the trick:

1. On the ECLIPSE top menu **FILE** pull down tab, select **NEW**, -->**Other**
2. ...on the *New Server: Select A Wizard* window, select: **Server**-> **Server**... click **NEXT**
3. . on the *New Server: Define a New Server* window, select **Apache> Tomcat 7 Server**
4. ..now click the line in blue and underlined entitled: ***Configure Runtime Environments***
5. on the *Server Runtime Environments* window,
6. ..select **Apache**, expand it(click on the arrow to the left), select **TOMCAT v7.0**, and click **EDIT**.
7. you will see a window called ***EDIT SERVER RUNTIME ENVIRONMENT: TOMCAT SERVER***
8. On this screen there is a pulldown labeled **JREs**.
9. You should find your JRE listed like **JRE1.6.0.33**. If not use the **Installed JRE** button.
10. Select the desired JRE. Click the **FINISH** button.
11. Gracefully exit, in the *Server: Server Runtime Environments* window, click **OK**
12. in the *New Server: Define a new Server* window, hit **NEXT**
13. in the *New Server: Add and Remove* Window, select apps and install them on the server.
14. in the *New Server: Add and Remove* Window, click **Finish**

That's all. Interesting, only steps 7-10 seem to matter, and they will change the JRE used on all servers you have previously defined to use TOMCAT v7.0. The rest of the steps are just because I can't find any other way to get to the screen except by defining a new server. Does anyone else know an easier way?

Comment: I have installed tomcat 6 using an .exe file [windows service] on windows 7 os. Thus I don't see the catalina.sh file in the bin directory for tomcat. Is there any other way, where I can change the jdk version mapped to such a tomcat installation?

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, Tomcat7 has a configuration file located at:

```
/etc/sysconfig/tomcat7
```

... which is where server specific configurations should be made. You can set the JAVA_HOME env variable here w/o needing to create a profile.d/ script.

This worked for me.

Comment: Not sure why the down-vote was made. A comment would be nice. Again this solution worked for me.

Comment: On which distribution of Linux did that work?  I get `ls: cannot access /etc/sysconfig/tomcat7: No such file or directory`

Comment: Amazon Web Service AMI Linux

Comment: @kostmo Check `/etc/default/tomcat7` (http://askubuntu.com/questions/154953/specify-jdk-for-tomcat7)

Answer (score 4):

There are several good answers on here but I wanted to add one since it may be helpful for users like me who have Tomcat installed as a service on a Windows machine.

Option 3 here: http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/4-ways-to-change-jre-for-tomcat

Basically, open tomcatw.exe and point Tomcat to the version of the JVM you need to use then restart the service. Ensure your deployed applications still work as well.

Comment: FYI: tomcatw reads its properties from the registry - e.g.: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat7\Parameters\Java

Answer (score 0):

For me, it got set from File > Project Structure > Project > sdk to right version and then apply and ok in Intellij from where I was running my tomcat.

Answer (score -1):

test
open the termenal or cmd.
go to the [tomcat-home]\bin directory. 
ex: c:\tomcat8\bin
write the following command: Tomcat8W //ES//Tomcat8
will open dialog, select the java tap(top tap).
change the Java virtual Machine value.