# How to configure Tomcat to use Java 7

Tags: java, tomcat, java-7

I have a web application in **java 6 byte code** and would like to test it in a Java 7 JVM environmment. 
For that purpose, I would like to configure Tomcat (for running the web application) to use **Java 7**. Now my question is how to do this?

Do I just set my **JAVA_HOME** environment variable to the path where Java 7 is installed, so that tomcat is run in the right JVM (Version 7)? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Either that or setting JAVA_HOME variable in catalina.bat/.sh.

Comment: I found this link to be very helpful, including setting the localhost server settings via eclipse: http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/4-ways-to-change-jre-for-tomcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your own question.! :)
All You need to do is link java 7 in your `JAVA_HOME`.!

More Info [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072272/876142)

**Edit :** (Based on [alfabravo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236345/alfabravo)'s comment :

You can definitely change the pointer to `JAVA_HOME` in your catalina.bat/sh

Answer (score 28):

If you're using Windows, this helps. Run Tomcat helper app (tomcatw.exe) and simply configure Java Virtual Machine DLL path under Java tab. Use default must be unchecked.

[image]

Comment: Not only did this help, but I also learned the Finnish word for "Cancel."   Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse it is very easy to point Tomcat to a new JVM (in this example JDK7). My problem was I couldn't find where to do it. Here is the trick:

1. On the ECLIPSE top menu **FILE** pull down tab, select **NEW**, -->**Other**
2. ...on the *New Server: Select A Wizard* window, select: **Server**-> **Server**... click **NEXT**
3. . on the *New Server: Define a New Server* window, select **Apache> Tomcat 7 Server**
4. ..now click the line in blue and underlined entitled: ***Configure Runtime Environments***
5. on the *Server Runtime Environments* window,
6. ..select **Apache**, expand it(click on the arrow to the left), select **TOMCAT v7.0**, and click **EDIT**.
7. you will see a window called ***EDIT SERVER RUNTIME ENVIRONMENT: TOMCAT SERVER***
8. On this screen there is a pulldown labeled **JREs**.
9. You should find your JRE listed like **JDK1.7.0**. If not use the **Installed JRE** button.
10. Select the desired JRE. Click the **FINISH** button.
11. Gracefully exit, in the *Server: Server Runtime Environments* window, click **OK**
12. in the *New Server: Define a new Server* window, hit **NEXT**
13. in the *New Server: Add and Remove* Window, select apps and install them on the server.
14. in the *New Server: Add and Remove* Window, click **Finish**

Thats all. Interesting, only steps 7-10 seem to matter, and they will change the JRE used on all servers you have previously defined to use TOMCAT v7.0. The rest of the steps are just because I can't find any other way to get to the screen except by defining a new server. Does anyone else know an easier way?

TA, Jalkin

Comment: Found this very useful. The way to do it without making a new server is to go to your server overview page (I do this by going to my servers tab and double clicking on the server's name, but there's probably a slicker way), and under general information it says "Runtime Environment". It looks like just a label for the drop-down next to it, but it's hyperlinked, and when you click it it'll take you to the Edit Server Runtime Environment window.

Answer (score 3):

I had installed it via

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

Setting up JAVA_HOME or PATH did not help me. I had to add entry in file-
/etc/default/tomcat7

```
# Run Tomcat as this user ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use the
# default of tomcat7.
TOMCAT7_USER=tomcat7

# Run Tomcat as this group ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use
# the default of tomcat7.
TOMCAT7_GROUP=tomcat7

# The home directory of the Java development kit (JDK). You need at least
# JDK version 1.5. If JAVA_HOME is not set, some common directories for 
# OpenJDK, the Sun JDK, and various J2SE 1.5 versions are tried.
#JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-6-jdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
...
```

This is Java 8 but you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

Go to tomcat/bin and modify the JAVA_HOME parmater in catalina.sh (for linux/unix) or catalina.bat (for windows). This means that only tomcat jvm will change, not everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat's home page states that

> Tomcat requires a JDK (version 1.6 or later) to be installed. The Sun
>   JDK can be downloaded here.
>
> IMPORTANT: Set an environment variable JAVA_HOME to the pathname of
>   the directory into which you installed the JDK release.

So basically you're correct. Still there might be some compatibility issues. I recommend you read [this article](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/08/25/apache-tomcat-8-and-java-7-will-they-work-together) for a detailed discussion about Tomcat and Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

Just Open the existing tomcat server and open Runtime Environment and check the JDK Version and change it java 7 [JDK Config Changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz6HO.png)

Comment: Please include the image inline, and the full description in text directly in the response