# Point Tomcat 7 to use different jdk

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

Read this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000497/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-use-java-7) but it doesn't work on my end. Also i couldn't change my JAVA_HOME because other applications are using it. How do configure Tomcat 7 to use a different jdk or jre 7 that is installed on my system?

I am using windows 7 and I have found this line in Catalina.bat but placing path of my java 7 installation directory in place of JAVA_HOME isn't working

```
if ""%1"" == ""debug"" goto use_jdk
echo Using JRE_HOME:        "%JRE_HOME%"
goto java_dir_displayed
:use_jdk
echo Using JAVA_HOME:       "%JAVA_HOME%"
```

## Found a solution [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt)

Just added a new batch file setenv.bat and saved the file in TOMCAT_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY\bin\setenv.bat or  %CATALINA_BASE%/bin/setenv.bat and restarted tomcat server.

Comment: and your system would be what?

Comment: many comments in your linked question suggest changing the value in the catalina.bat file - did you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

catalina.bat should have setLocal endLocal

which means when batch file runs it uses that JAVA_HOME but on exiting it does not change system variable for other apps

changing bat file should work