# Tomcat Installation - JAVA_HOME error

Tags: tomcat

I have installed Apache Tomcat v7.0.77  in Linux. But when I try to start it up, tomcat starts but throws an error in the log file:

> line 415: path/to/JAVA_HOME/bin/java: No such file or directory

and

> INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal
>   performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path:
>   /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib

Comment: not really an answer but this on SO might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072260/how-to-change-java-version-used-by-tomcat/4072272#4072272

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved by setting JAVA_HOME in .bash_profile file