# How to upgrade Java in tomcat server?

Tags: java, unix, tomcat7, upgrade

My server is in a Unix environment. And I'm using tomcat server. I'm trying to upgrade the Java version, but tomcat is not starting after the upgrade.

`which java` still gives the old version.

Below is the script for java pointing to tomcat:

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" -a -z "$JRE_HOME" ]; then
    some script
fi
else
    JAVA_PATH=`which java 2>/dev/null`
    if [ "x$JAVA_PATH" != "x" ]; then
      JAVA_PATH=`dirname $JAVA_PATH 2>/dev/null`
      JRE_HOME=`dirname $JAVA_PATH 2>/dev/null`
    fi
    if [ "x$JRE_HOME" = "x" ]; then
      if [ -x /usr/bin/java ]; then
        JRE_HOME=/usr
      fi
    fi
  fi
  if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" -a -z "$JRE_HOME" ]; then
    echo "Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined"
    echo "At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program"
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

Comment: `export JAVA_HOME=/my/java/path/`

Comment: whee exactly in the script is it defining the java path? @Michael

Comment: What is your tomcat version? What is your current Java version, to which Java version are you trying to upgrade? What errors occur when you start tomcat after upgrading?

Comment: @SushmithaK The script doesn't define the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. It should be in the user's environment. Add it to their `~/.bashrc` or equivalent.

Comment: i am upgrading from java 1.7_45 to 1.7_8. and i am suing tomcat7. Tomcat doesnt start after the upgrade. @MarkRotteveel

Comment: i am pretty new to unix. Where can i find the ~/.bashrc or equivalent? @Michael

Comment: Please update your question with information, don't use comments. In what way is going from 1.7_45 to 1.7_8 an upgrade? That sounds like a downgrade (unless you provided the wrong version nr). And _"doesn't start"_ is not enough information. You should have an error somewhere, either in the tomcat logs, or on the console when starting tomcat.

Comment: @SushmithaK `~/.bashrc` is the path of the file. `~` means the user's home directory. `.bashrc` is the name of the file. [The period denotes that it is "hidden"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94780/what-are-dot-files)

Comment: @Michael how can i update the jre path? I am having a really tough time to find where we declard the jre/java path?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat uses `JAVA_HOME` variable to get the path for `Java`. So the question drills down to *how you set `JAVA_HOME` and where to set it*?

You might find `JAVA_HOME` under `less /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh` **depending on which shell you are using**. I am using `cshell` so its under `/etc/profile.d/jdk.csh`

If you will check `less /etc/profile`, this is the file which is loaded when a user logs in. There is a variable called as PATH the value for which might be something like `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` so you can access any executable under these paths.

The line in ponder in `/etc/profile` is `for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh` from where all the variable (in case of `bash`) will be loaded into the environment. Also, it's important to note, if you are setting values here these variable will be set for all the users not just for one.

You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072260/how-to-change-java-version-used-by-tomcat) answer useful.

Comment: Some of the discussion for this question is done at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475870/upgrade-java-jre-path-in-tomcat7