# What determines which version of Java Tomcat uses on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, tomcat, systemd

I have two Ubuntu 20.04 servers, Alpha and Beta, both with Tomcat 9 installed from the standard repo.  In principle, they should be virtually identical, but I've found a discrepancy in which version of Java each uses that I can't find the origin of.

On server Alpha, both the `ps` process listing for Tomcat and `systemctl status tomcat9.service` show that its Java binary is  `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`.  On server Beta, the same commands show that Tomcat's Java binary is `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java`, which is a symlink to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`.

Thus, server Alpha uses Java 8, while server Beta uses Java 11.  They should be identical, yet something is clearly different.

The obvious question at this point is, **how does Tomcat determine which version of Java to use?**

**1) Documentation**

I cannot find the answer to this question in the [Tomcat configuration documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/index.html), and there are no other top-level topics in the documentation that seem relevant to this question.

**2) Stack Overflow**

This Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072260/how-to-change-java-version-used-by-tomcat) is the best I can find on the site, and it doesn't have any useful answers for an Ubuntu system; `/etc/sysconfig/tomcat{N}` is mentioned in one answer, but it does not exist on either server, while `/etc/default/tomcat{N}` exists on both but does not contain any parameters relating to Java version.

**3) Standard config files**

I have also checked the main Tomcat config file `/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/server.xml` and the Tomcat `systemd` service file `/lib/systemd/system/tomcat9.service`, but neither contain any parameters relating to Java version.  Both servers have a service file override `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat9.service.d/override.conf`, but since I wrote that myself, I'm certain it doesn't set the version of Java used.

**4) setenv.sh**

Tomcat's `/usr/share/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh` file mentions a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, which I have to assume is what I'm looking for.  That file appears to expect this variable to be set when it sources one of two files, `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh` or `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh`.  Neither of these files (or `bin/` directories, even) exist on either server, so this can't explain the difference.

That's all I can figure out.  The question is:

**In the absence of explicit user configuration, what determines what Java version Tomcat uses?**  This information must be stored in one of the files in Tomcat's installation, but I have no way of knowing which one.

**EDIT**

As @Emerson Pardo suggested, the two instances of Ubuntu 20.04 *did* have different default Java versions.  After changing Beta's to use Java 8 using the Debian/Ubuntu `update-alternatives` program and restarting Tomcat, however, the problem outlined above is unchanged.  Tomcat continues to use

```
/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

on Beta.

Comment: Is it specific to Tomcat? If you run `java --version` on both servers, what do you get?

Comment: @GaëlJ  `java --version` on Alpha gives an error `Unrecognized option: --version`.  On Beta, it gave `openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20` until I tried @Emerson Pardo's suggestion.  Now it gives `Unrecognized option: --version`.  See my first comment on that answer, it seems to be Tomcat-specific.

Comment: Okay, the version check must have changed between Java 8 and 11.  For 8, it's `java -version`, with one dash, and it gives `openjdk version "1.8.0_292"` on both servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On derivatives of Debian 10, such as Ubuntu 20.04, Tomcat is started through a wrapper script located  in `/usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-start.sh`. If you don't set `JAVA_HOME` yourself a heuristic procedure is performed in `/usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-locate-java.sh`:

```sh
    # This function sets the variable JDK_DIRS
    find_jdks()
    {
        for java_version in 11 10 9 8
        do
            for jvmdir in /usr/lib/jvm/java-${java_version}-openjdk-* \
                          /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-${java_version}-oracle-* \
                          /usr/lib/jvm/jre-${java_version}-oracle-* \
                          /usr/lib/jvm/java-${java_version}-oracle \
                          /usr/lib/jvm/oracle-java${java_version}-jdk-* \
                          /usr/lib/jvm/oracle-java${java_version}-jre-*
            do
                if [ -d "${jvmdir}" ]
                then
                    JDK_DIRS="${JDK_DIRS} ${jvmdir}"
                fi
            done
        done
    }

    # The first existing directory is used for JAVA_HOME
    JDK_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
    find_jdks

    # Look for the right JVM to use
    for jdir in $JDK_DIRS; do
        if [ -r "$jdir/bin/java" -a -z "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
            JAVA_HOME="$jdir"
        fi
    done
    export JAVA_HOME
```

Therefore:

- if `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` exists it is chosen,
- otherwise the highest (up to 11) version of Java is used.

Comment: This is precisely what I needed to know, thank you!  One green checkmark doesn't seem like enough.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, Ubuntu chooses what Java it will be used by default. You can find it like this:

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$/usr/bin/java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20                                                                                                                                                         
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04)                                                                                                                
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

You can also check the alternatives available in your system using:

```
$ update-java-alternatives -l
```

which will list all java installed.

To choose a specific version you can use:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this, and it turned out that the two Ubuntu installations had different default Java symlinks.  However, even after setting both servers to use Java 8 in the manner you suggest, and restarting Tomcat, Tomcat still uses `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java` as its Java version, and that still symlinks to Java 11.  There appears to still be a Tomcat-specific difference between the two servers.

Comment: Check the item 3.4 of this documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/RUNNING.txt. You will have to set JAVA_HOME in the `setenv.sh`. For example: `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/path-to-your-java8"`

Comment: I don't have an active `setenv.sh` on either server (as far as I can tell), so that doesn't explain it.  I know that I can use `setenv.sh`, but this question is limited to determining the cause of the discrepancy as it exists now.

Comment: Maybe another application (maybe the java installer) have set up the JAVA_HOME for the system. Try this: `echo $JAVA_HOME`. If it prints a path, check the version: `path-from-the-echo/bin/java -version`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the problem that I want to run tomcat with java version 8 instead of the default version.

I edit `/usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-locate-java.sh`. I add:

```
# run tomcat with Java version 8
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

at start of file. To get possible values do:

```
$ls -l /usr/lib/jvm
default-java -> java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-11-openjdk-amd64
java-11-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-8-openjdk-amd64
java-8-openjdk-amd64
```